# Accessing one item in a group

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ to SQL query that is grouping items like so:

```
var myGroup = (from ps in this.Context.PersonSpecialties
    where personKeys.Contains(ps.Person_K)
    group ps.SpecialtyName by ps.Person_K).ToList();
```

How can I check if there is anything in this result that its key is "A12345" ?
And if there is, go grab its list of items.

Comment: It''s not clear without knowing more of the data structure, but does just adding `.Where(g => g.Key == "A12345").SelectMany(g => g)` work?

Comment: `var myGroup = from ps in this.Context.PersonSpecialties
    group ps.SpecialtyName by ps.Person_K into x
 select x.First();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are looking for a way to query your groups with multiple keys, because otherwise it would be much easier to filter for that one key directly (instead of building a group and then discarding everything except for that single item that you need).

In this case you would be better off calling `ToDictionary` on the groups, and then querying the dictionary for the lists by key, like this:

```
var groupByKey = (from ps in this.Context.PersonSpecialties
    where personKeys.Contains(ps.Person_K)
    group ps.SpecialtyName by ps.Person_K).ToDictionary(g => g.Key);
// Now you can get your lists with a simple look-up
IEnumerable<PersonSpeciality> listForA12345 = groupByKey["A12345"];
IEnumerable<PersonSpeciality> listForB23456 = groupByKey["B23456"];
...
IEnumerable<PersonSpeciality> listForA12345 = groupByKey["Z22232"];
```